# Understanding 'gslider' function to make interactive plots

Tags: r, slider, tcl, histogram, tk-toolkit

I am trying to create an interactive histogram in R whose bin width can be adjusted either by moving a slider or entering a value in the text box. In addition to this, I would also like to provide the user with an option of saving the plot for a particular bin width.

To this end, I found the 'gslider' function of 'aplpack' library to be a good starting point. I tried to modify it to meet my purpose as well as learn more about Tcl/Tk constructs. But I am now stuck and can't proceed, mostly because I haven't completely understood how a slider value is captured and transferred between functions.

Following are the snippets of code that I haven't really understood. These are from the source code of the 'gslider' function.

```
# What is the rationale behind using the 'assign' function here and at 
# other instances in the code?

  img <- tkrplot::tkrplot(gr.frame, newpl, vscale = 1, hscale = 1)
  tkpack(img, side = "top")
  assign("img", img, envir = slider.env)

# I understand the below lines when considered individually. But collectively,
# I am having a difficult time comprehending them. Most importantly, where 
# exactly is the slider movement captured here?

  sc <- tkscale(fr, from = sl.min, to = sl.max, 
              showvalue = TRUE, resolution = sl.delta, orient = "horiz")
  assign("sc", sc, envir = slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(sc, variable=inputbw1)"), envir = slider.env)
  sl.fun <- sl.function
  if (!is.function(sl.fun)) 
    sl.fun <- eval(parse(text = paste("function(...){", 
                                    sl.fun, "}")))
    fname <- 'tkrrsl.fun1'
    eval(parse(text = c(paste(fname, " <-"), " function(...){", 
                    "tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function()", 
                    deparse(sl.fun)[-1], ")", "}")))
    eval(parse(text = paste("environment(", fname, ")<-parent.env")))
    if (prompt) 
      tkconfigure(sc, command = get(fname))
    else tkbind(sc, "<ButtonRelease>", get(fname))

  if (exists("tkrrsl.fun1")) {
    get("tkrrsl.fun1")()
  } 
  assign("slider.values.old", sl.default, envir = slider.env)
```

Thanks to everyone for the varied scope of answers. Juba's and Greg's answers were the ones I could work upon to write the following code:

```
slider_txtbox <- function (x, col=1, sl.delta, title) 
{
  ## Validations
  require(tkrplot)
  pos.of.panel <- 'bottom'
  if(is.numeric(col))
    col <- names(x)[col]
  x <- x[,col, drop=FALSE]
  if (missing(x) || is.null(dim(x))) 
     return("Error: insufficient x values")
  sl.min <- sl.delta # Smarter initialization required
  sl.max <- max(x)
  xrange <- (max(x)-min(x))
  sl.default <- xrange/30
  if (!exists("slider.env")) {
    slider.env <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)    
  }
  if (missing(title)) 
    title <- "Adjust parameters"

  ## Creating initial dialogs
  require(tcltk)
  nt <- tktoplevel()
  tkwm.title(nt, title)
  if(.Platform$OS.type == 'windows')
    tkwm.geometry(nt, "390x490+0+10")
  else if(.Platform$OS.type == 'unix')
     tkwm.geometry(nt, "480x600+0+10")
  assign("tktop.slider", nt, envir = slider.env)
  "relax"
  nt.bak <- nt
  sl.frame <- tkframe(nt)
  gr.frame <- tkframe(nt)
  tx.frame <- tkframe(nt)
  tkpack(sl.frame, tx.frame, gr.frame, side = pos.of.panel)

  ## Function to create and refresh the plot
  library(ggplot2)
  library(gridExtra)
  makeplot <- function(bwidth, save) {
    if(bwidth <= 0) {
      df <- data.frame('x'=1:10, 'y'=1:10)
       histplot <- ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(size=0) + xlim(0, 10) +  ylim(0, 100) + 
    geom_text(aes(label='Invalid binwidth...', x=5, y=50), size=9)
    } else {

    histplot <- ggplot(data=x, aes_string(x=col)) +
  geom_histogram(binwidth=bwidth, aes(y = ..density..), fill='skyblue') + 
  theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=15), axis.title.y=element_text(size=15), 
        axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, colour='black'),
        axis.text.y=element_text(size=10, colour='black'))
    }
    print(histplot)
    if(save){
  filename <- tkgetSaveFile(initialfile=paste('hist_bw_', bwidth, sep=''), 
                            filetypes='{{PNG files} {.png}} {{JPEG files} {.jpg .jpeg}}
                            {{PDF file} {.pdf}} {{Postscript file} {.ps}}')
  filepath <- as.character(filename)
  splitpath <- strsplit(filepath, '/')[[1]]
  flname <- splitpath[length(splitpath)]
  pieces <- strsplit(flname, "\\.")[[1]]
  ext <- tolower(pieces[length(pieces)])
  if(ext != 'png' && ext != 'jpeg' && ext != 'jpg' && ext != 'pdf' && ext != 'ps') {
    ext <- 'png'
    filepath <- paste(filepath, '.png', sep='')
    filename <- tclVar(filepath)
  }
  if(ext == 'ps')
    ext <- 'postscript'
  eval(parse(text=paste(ext, '(file=filepath)', sep='')))
  eval(parse(text='print(histplot)'))
  dev.off()
}
  }
  img <- tkrplot::tkrplot(gr.frame, makeplot(sl.default, FALSE), vscale = 1, hscale = 1)
  tkpack(img, side = "top")
  assign("img", img, envir = slider.env)

  ## Creating slider, textbox and labels
  parent.env <- sys.frame(sys.nframe() - 1)
  tkpack(fr <- tkframe(sl.frame), side = 'top')
  sc <- tkscale(fr, from = sl.min, to = sl.max, 
            showvalue = TRUE, resolution = sl.delta,
            orient = "horiz")
  tb <- tkentry(fr, width=4)
  labspace <- tklabel(fr, text='\t\t\t')
  tkpack(sc, labspace, tb, side = 'left')

  tkpack(textinfo <- tkframe(tx.frame), side = 'top')
  lab <- tklabel(textinfo, text = '                    Move slider', width = "20")
  orlabel <- tklabel(textinfo, text='          OR', width='10')
  txtboxmsg <- tklabel(textinfo, text = 'Enter binwidth', width='20')
  tkpack(txtboxmsg, orlabel, lab, side='right')

  tkpack(f.but <- tkframe(sl.frame))
  tkpack(tklabel(f.but, text=''))
  tkpack(tkbutton(f.but, text = "Exit", command = function() tkdestroy(nt)), 
     side='right')
  tkpack(tkbutton(f.but, text = "Save", command = function(...) {
    bwidth <- as.numeric(tclvalue(get('inputtb', envir=slider.env)))
    tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function() { makeplot(bwidth, TRUE); sync_slider()})
  }), side='right')

  ## Creating objects and variables associated with slider and textbox
  assign("sc", sc, envir = slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "assign('inputsc', tclVar(sl.default), envir=slider.env)"))
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(sc, variable=inputsc)"), envir = slider.env)

  assign("tb", tb, envir = slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "assign('inputtb', as.character(tclVar(sl.default)),
         envir=slider.env)"))
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)

  ## Function to update the textbox value when the slider has changed
  sync_textbox <- function() {
  bwidth_sl <- tclvalue(get('inputsc', envir=slider.env))
  assign('inputtb', tclVar(bwidth_sl), envir=slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)
}

 ## Function to update the slider value when the textbox has changed
 sync_slider <- function() {
 bwidth_tb <- tclvalue(get('inputtb', envir=slider.env))
 assign('inputsc', tclVar(bwidth_tb), envir=slider.env)
 eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(sc, variable=inputsc)"), envir = slider.env)
}  

  ## Bindings : association of certain functions to certain events for the slider
  ## and the textbox

  tkbind(sc, "<ButtonRelease>", function(...) {
    bwidth <- as.numeric(tclvalue(get('inputsc', envir=slider.env)))
    tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function() { makeplot(bwidth, FALSE); sync_textbox()})
  })

  tkbind(tb, "<Return>", function(...) {
    bwidth <- as.numeric(tclvalue(get('inputtb', envir=slider.env)))
    if(bwidth > sl.max && !is.na(bwidth)) {
      bwidth <- sl.max
      assign('inputtb', tclVar(bwidth), envir=slider.env)
      eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)
     } else
    if(bwidth < sl.min || is.na(bwidth)) {
      bwidth <- sl.min
      assign('inputtb', tclVar(bwidth), envir=slider.env)
      eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)
     }
  tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function() { makeplot(bwidth, FALSE);    sync_slider()})
})

}

library(ggplot2)
slider_txtbox(movies, 'rating', 0.1, 'Adjust binwidth')
```

Comment: Sorry, not really an answer, but if it fits your needs you could also build a local Web app with [shiny](http://www.rstudio.com/shiny/), I think the code would be quite simpler.

Comment: "mostly because I haven't completely understood how a slider value is captured and transferred between functions" That seems to be your actual question. I am not sure if you need so many lines of code to illustrate that issue.

Comment: @juba I have to use Tcl/Tk based graphics to integrate this histogram into a larger project. Thanks for the info on Shiny!

Comment: @Roland I posted the entire code so as to provide a reproducible code. I agree with you that I might have littered my question with unnecessary information. I shall edit it.

Comment: I admit not knowing how Tcl's variables are integrated with R, but they all support a system of observer callbacks; a change to a slider can give a callback that allows you to trigger a recomputation of the plot. Getting it working well can take a lot of tuning though, especially if the recomputation is itself expensive…

Comment: The rationale behind the use of `assign` here is to assign values to variables into a given environment, where every variable related to your sliders and widgets are "protected". That's why you don't just use `<-` but explicitly `assign`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example with comments, based on the complete code you first submit. As I'm far from an expert in tcl/tk, there may be cleaner or better ways to do it. And it is quite incomplete (for example the textbox values should be checked to be in the range of the slider, etc.) :

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
title <- "Default title"
data(movies)

## Init dialog
require(tkrplot)
if (!exists("slider.env")) slider.env <<- new.env(parent = .GlobalEnv)
require(tcltk)
nt <- tktoplevel()
tkwm.title(nt, title)
tkwm.geometry(nt, "480x600+0+10")
assign("tktop.slider", nt, envir = slider.env)
"relax"
nt.bak <- nt
sl.frame <- tkframe(nt)
gr.frame <- tkframe(nt)
tx.frame <- tkframe(nt)
tkpack(sl.frame, tx.frame, gr.frame, side = "bottom")
## First default plot
newpl <- function(...) {
  dummydf <- data.frame('x'=1:10, 'y'=1:10)
  dummy <- ggplot(dummydf, aes(x=x, y=y)) + geom_point(size=0) + xlim(0, 10) + ylim(0, 100) + 
    geom_text(aes(label='Generating plot...', x=5, y=50), size=9)
  print(dummy)
  }
img <- tkrplot::tkrplot(gr.frame, newpl, vscale = 1, hscale = 1)
tkpack(img, side = "top")
assign("img", img, envir = slider.env)
tkpack(fr <- tkframe(sl.frame), side = 'top')

## Creating slider, textbox and labels
sc <- tkscale(fr, from = 0, to = 5, showvalue = TRUE, resolution = 0.1, orient = "horiz")
tb <- tkentry(fr, width=4)
lab <- tklabel(fr, text = 'Select binwidth ', width = "16")
orlabel <- tklabel(fr, text=' or ', width='4')
tkpack(lab, sc, orlabel, tb, side = 'left')
tkpack(textinfo <- tkframe(tx.frame), side = 'top')


## Creating objects and variables associated with slider and textbox
assign("sc", sc, envir = slider.env)
assign("tb", tb, envir = slider.env)
assign('inputsc', tclVar(2.5), envir=slider.env)
assign('inputtb', tclVar('2.5'), envir=slider.env)
eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(sc, variable=inputsc)"), envir = slider.env)
eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)

## Function to update the textbox value when the slider has changed
sync_textbox <- function() {
  bwidth_sl <- tclvalue(get('inputsc', envir=slider.env))
  assign('inputtb', tclVar(bwidth_sl), envir=slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(tb, textvariable=inputtb)"), envir = slider.env)
}

## Function to update the slider value when the textbox has changed
sync_slider <- function() {
  bwidth_tb <- tclvalue(get('inputtb', envir=slider.env))
  assign('inputsc', tclVar(bwidth_tb), envir=slider.env)
  eval(parse(text = "tkconfigure(sc, variable=inputsc)"), envir = slider.env)
}

## Function to refresh the plot
refresh <- function(bwidth) {
  histplot <- ggplot(data=movies, aes_string(x="rating")) +
     geom_histogram(binwidth=bwidth, 
                    aes(y = ..density..), fill='skyblue') + 
                      theme(axis.title.x=element_text(size=15), axis.title.y=element_text(size=15), 
                            axis.text.x=element_text(size=10, colour='black'),
                            axis.text.y=element_text(size=10, colour='black'))
  print(histplot)
}

## Bindings : association of certain functions to certain events for the slider
## and the textbox

tkbind(sc, "<ButtonRelease>", function(...) {
  bwidth <- as.numeric(tclvalue(get('inputsc', envir=slider.env)))
  tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function() { refresh(bwidth); sync_textbox()})
})

tkbind(tb, "<Return>", function(...) {
  bwidth <- as.numeric(tclvalue(get('inputtb', envir=slider.env)))
  tkrreplot(get('img',envir=slider.env),fun=function() { refresh(bwidth); sync_slider()})
})
```

Comment: Thanks for the code, juba. I modified it slightly to get the result I desired. I have added the code as an edit to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

*If you do not insist on a local solution*, you might give [rapporter.net](http://rapporter.net) a try, which lets you specify such tasks easily with any number of tweakable sliders. Okay, enough of marketing :)

Here goes a quick demo:  [Interactive histogram on `mtcars`](http://rapporter.net/api/form/81c47ee7512ffab02db48b974e6bbf0373f033974063e83e8f600e0214d7d728) which looks like:

[image: Interactive histogram demo on rapporter.net]

There you could choose one of the well-know variables of `mtcars`, but of course you could provide any data frame to be used here or tweak the above form after a free registration.

---

How it's done? I have just created a quick [rapport](http://rapport-package.info) template and let it [rapplicate](http://www.r-bloggers.com/lets-rapplicate/). The body of the template is written in brew-style (please see the above "rapport" URL for more details):

```
<%=
evalsOptions('width', width)
evalsOptions('height', height)
%>

# Histogram

<%=
set.caption(paste('Histogram of', var.name))
hist(var, breaks=seq(min(var), max(var), diff(range(var))/round(binwidth)), main = paste('Histogram of', var.name), xlab = '')
%>

## Parameters

Provided parameters were:

  * variable: <%=var.name%> (<%=var.label%>)
  * bin-width of histogram: <%=binwidth%>
  * height of generated images: <%=height%>
  * width of generated images: <%=width%>

# Kernel density plot

<%=
set.caption('A kernel density plot')
plot(density(var), main = '', xlab = '')
%>
```

But a bare-minimal example of the task could be also addressed by a simple one-liner template:

```
<%=hist(var, breaks=seq(min(var), max(var), diff(range(var))/round(binwidth)))%>
```

There you would only need to create a new *template*, add two input types with a click (one `numeric` variable of any data set and a `number` input field which would hold the `binwidth` of the histogram), and you are ready to go.

Comment: rapporter looks like an interesting project, but at least some of us prefer not to write code that depends on "cloud" sites, or for that matter on the existence of an internet connection at all.  I'd love to see your project spin off an R-package as well!

Comment: Thanks @CarlWitthoft for the feedback, and of course I am aware of the fact that most advanced R users would stick to local resources. To be honest, we started our project 2 years ago with [rapport](http://rapport-package.info) as an R package and just started to build a front-end in the cloud later.
Currently, we are also working on some helpers in `rapport` to let users generate that HTML form in a local web-server (so that you do not have to type commands in R console), possibly with some cooperation with `shiny`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the R package 'rpanel' -- it uses tcltk under the hood but is much simpler to use:

[rpanel](http://www.jstatsoft.org/v17/i09/paper)

[rpanel reference](http://www.stats.gla.ac.uk/~adrian/rpanel/rpanel_quick_reference.pdf)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the gslider function and cannot help you there, but here are some alternatives:

One simple option is to use the `tkexamp` function from the TeachingDemos package, here is one way:

```
library(TeachingDemos)

myhist <- function(x, s.width, e.width, ...) {
    if( missing(e.width) || is.null(e.width) || is.na(e.width) ) {
        e.width<- s.width
    }
    b <- seq( min(x)-e.width/2, max(x)+e.width, by=e.width )
    hist(x, b, ...)
}

mylist <- list( s.width=list('slider', init=1, from=1, to=10, resolution=1),
    e.width=list('numentry', init='', width=7)
)

sampdata <- rnorm(100, 50, 5)
tkexamp(myhist(sampdata), mylist)
```

This will create a quick GUI with your histogram and a slider and entry widget.  The width of the bars are determined by the value in the entry widget, and if that is blank (default) then the value of the slider.  Unfortunately the slider and entry widget do not update each other.  There is a button that will print out the current call, so the same plot can be recreated from the command line in the default or current plotting device.  You can edit the `mylist` variable above to make the controls fit your data better.

If you want the entry and slider to update each other then you can program that more directly.  Here is a basic function that uses `tkrplot`:

```
mytkhist <- function(x, ...) {

    width <- tclVar()
    tclvalue(width) <- 1

    replot <- function(...) {
        width <- as.numeric(tclvalue(width))
        b <- seq( min(x) - width/2, max(x)+width, by=width )
        hist(x,b,...)
    }

    tt <- tktoplevel()
    img <- tkrplot(tt, replot)
    tkpack(img, side='top')

    tkpack( tkscale(tt, variable=width, from=1, to=10,
        command=function(...) tkrreplot(img),
        orient='horizontal'), side='top' )
    tkpack( e <- tkentry(tt, textvariable=width), side='top' )
    tkbind(e, "<KeyRelease>", function(...) tkrreplot(img))
}

mytkhist(sampdata)
```

The fact that both the slider (scale) and the entry widget use the same variable is what makes them automatically update each other (no calls to `assign` needed).  The `command` argument in `tkscale` and the `tkbind` call mean that any changes to either the slider or the entry will update the plot.  This does not have anything to save the current plot, but you should be able to add that part as well as any other controls that you want to use.

Comment: Greg, thanks for alternative. Your logic to keep the slider and text box values in sync is certainly shorter than Juba's. But entering a value in the text box is quite cumbersome as it immediately gets updated to a valid value. I had come across some forum post that talked about slightly delaying this updating of values but can't find it now. Do you have any hint about it?

Comment: @tejas_kale, you can remove the `tkbind` statement and instead create a button that would then update the plot (`tkexamp` uses this model for entry widgets).  Or you could use `TkTaskSchedule` or similar from the tcltk2 package to just check every couple of seconds to see if the entry has changed and update if it has.  You could also change the binding to only update on certain keys (such as the return/enter key) then it would update on return but not just changing the numbers.